# Self-joined data to hierarchical XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, recursive-query

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 with self-joined data like this:

```
 ID   | ChildA_ID | ChildB_ID
(int) |   (int)   |   (int)
-----------------------------
 1    |           |     
 2    | 1         |     
 3    | 1         |     
 4    | 3         |     
 6    | 2         | 4
 7    | 6         |
```

Using T-SQL (or, in a pinch, CLR code), I would like to turn it into XML that looks like this:

```
<row>
  <ID>7</ID>
  <ChildA>
    <row>
      <ID>6</ID>
      <ChildA>
        <row>
          <ID>2</ID>
          <ChildA>
            <row>
              <ID>1</ID>
            </row>
          </ChildA>
        </row>
      </ChildA>
      <ChildB>
        <row>
          <ID>4</ID>
          <ChildA>
            <row>
              <ID>3</ID>
              <ChildA>
                <row>
                  <ID>1</ID>
                </row>
              </ChildA>
            </row>
          </ChildA>
        </row>
      </ChildB>
    </row>
  </ChildA>
</row>
```

I have a fair amount of experience with recursive CTEs in SQL Server and the `FOR XML` clause, but this one has me well and truly stumped. (I don't discount the possibility that I'm simply pulling a dumb.)

Any suggestions are welcome, including alternate ways of structuring the data in order to achieve the desired result. (Note, however, that "ChildA" and "ChildB" represent different *types* of parent-child relationships, not denormalization.)

#### EDIT:

When trying Mitch's solution with my sample data, I ran into some duplicate rows:

```
<row>
  <ID>7</ID>
  <ChildA>
    <row>
      <ID>6</ID>
      <ChildA>
        <row>
          <ID>2</ID>
          <ChildA>
            <row>
              <ID>1</ID>
            </row>
          </ChildA>
        </row>
<!--This is the first duplicate row:-->
        <row>
          <ID>2</ID>
          <ChildA>
            <row>
              <ID>1</ID>
            </row>
          </ChildA>
        </row>
      </ChildA>
      <ChildB>
        <row>
          <ID>4</ID>
          <ChildA>
<!--This is the second "duplicate" row:-->
            <row>
              <ID>3</ID>
            </row>
            <row>
              <ID>3</ID>
              <ChildA>
                <row>
                  <ID>1</ID>
                </row>
              </ChildA>
            </row>
          </ChildA>
        </row>
      </ChildB>
    </row>
  </ChildA>
</row>
```

#### EDIT 2:

Here is the code I used to generate the above result (slightly modified version of Mitch's solution):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Nodes') 
    CREATE TABLE Nodes (id int, leftid int, rightid int);

DELETE FROM Nodes

INSERT INTO Nodes
VALUES (1, null, null),
       (2, 1, null),
       (3, 1, null),
       (4, 3, null), 
       (6, 2, 4),
       (7, 6, null);

CREATE TABLE #xml (id int, depth int, data xml);

DECLARE @rootNode int = 7;

WITH cte (cid, depth, child) as 
(
  -- anchor
  SELECT id, 1, leftid
  FROM nodes
  WHERE id = @rootNode and leftid is not null
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id, 1, rightid
  FROM nodes
  WHERE id = @rootNode and rightid is not null
  UNION ALL 
  -- recursive
  SELECT n.id, depth + 1, leftid
  FROM cte c
  INNER JOIN nodes n on c.child = n.id
  WHERE leftid is not null or (rightid is null and leftid is null)
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT n.id, depth + 1, rightid
  FROM cte c
  INNER JOIN nodes n on c.child = n.id
  WHERE rightid is not null
)
INSERT INTO #xml (id, depth, data)
SELECT DISTINCT cid, depth, null
FROM CTE;

DECLARE @maxDepth int;
SET @maxDepth = (SELECT MAX(depth) FROM #xml)

WHILE @MaxDepth > 0
BEGIN
  UPDATE xu
  SET data = (
    SELECT n.ID, xl.data as ChildA, xr.data as ChildB
    FROM Nodes n
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #xml xl on n.leftid = xl.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #xml xr on n.rightid = xr.id
    WHERE xu.id = n.id
    FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE
  )
  FROM #xml xu
  WHERE xu.Depth = @MaxDepth

  SET @MaxDepth = @MaxDepth - 1
END

SELECT data FROM #xml WHERE id = @RootNode

DROP TABLE #xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do these sorts of translations by doing a depth first search.  Use a recursive CTE to calculate the depth, then a loop to convert to XML:

[Example SQL (Fiddle):](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87118/14)

```
CREATE TABLE Nodes (id int, leftid int, rightid int, name varchar(256));

INSERT INTO Nodes
VALUES (1, 2, 3, 'abcd'),
       (2, 4, 5, 'ab'),
       (4, null, null, 'a'), 
       (5, null, null, 'b'),
       (3, 6, 7, 'cd'),
       (6, null, null, 'c'),
       (7, null, null, 'd');

CREATE TABLE #xml (id int, depth int, data xml, parent int);

DECLARE @rootNode int = 1;

WITH cte (cid, depth, child, parent) as 
(
  -- anchor
  SELECT id, 1, leftid, cast(null as int)
  FROM nodes
  WHERE id = @rootNode and leftid is not null
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id, 1, righted, null
  FROM nodes
  WHERE id = @rootNode and rightid is not null
  UNION ALL 
  -- recursive
  SELECT n.id, depth + 1, leftid, c.cid
  FROM cte c
  INNER JOIN nodes n on c.child = n.id
  WHERE leftid is not null or (rightid is null and leftid is null)
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT n.id, depth + 1, rightid, c.cid
  FROM cte c
  INNER JOIN nodes n on c.child = n.id
  WHERE rightid is not null
)
INSERT INTO #xml (id, depth, data, parent)
SELECT DISTINCT cid, depth, null, parent
FROM CTE;

DECLARE @maxDepth int;
SET @maxDepth = (SELECT MAX(depth) FROM #xml)

WHILE @MaxDepth > 0
BEGIN
  UPDATE xu
  SET data = (
    SELECT n.Name, xl.data as [Left], xr.data as [Right]
    FROM Nodes n
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #xml xl on n.leftid = xl.id and xl.parent = n.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #xml xr on n.rightid = xr.id and xr.parent = n.id
    WHERE xu.id = n.id
    FOR XML PATH('TreeNode'), TYPE
  )
  FROM #xml xu
  WHERE xu.Depth = @MaxDepth

  SET @MaxDepth = @MaxDepth - 1
END

SELECT data FROM #xml WHERE id = @RootNode
```

Produces:

```
<TreeNode>
  <Name>abcd</Name>
  <Left>
    <TreeNode>
      <Name>ab</Name>
      <Left>
        <TreeNode>
          <Name>a</Name>
        </TreeNode>
      </Left>
      <Right>
        <TreeNode>
          <Name>b</Name>
        </TreeNode>
      </Right>
    </TreeNode>
  </Left>
  <Right>
    <TreeNode>
      <Name>cd</Name>
      <Left>
        <TreeNode>
          <Name>c</Name>
        </TreeNode>
      </Left>
      <Right>
        <TreeNode>
          <Name>d</Name>
        </TreeNode>
      </Right>
    </TreeNode>
  </Right>
</TreeNode>
```

Comment: This seems like a very good solution, but I'm getting some duplicate rows when I run it with my sample data. I have tried to fix this myself, but I'm still coming up short. Can you help? See the edit for details.

Comment: Put it in a http://sqlfiddle.com/ or post your SQL.  As it stands, I see the duplicate, but cannot say how you are generating them.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the question again and added my modified version of your code. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a graph rather than a tree, so a node cannot be uniquely identified.  Use the parent → child relationship to uniquely identify a node and it works out (`n.leftid = xl.id` → `n.leftid = xl.id and n.id = xl.parent`).  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c983/7.  I have also updated my sample.

Answer (score 1):

Well sql can do a lot of ugly things; the trick is to move recursion to hand-made stack as  luxury of recurrent calls is somehow limited:

```
 declare @tmp table(id int, ChildA_id int, ChildB_ID int)
 declare @xml xml
 select @xml = ''
 insert into @tmp
 select       1    , NULL      , NULL    
 union select 2    , 1         , NULL    
 union select 3    , 1         , NULL    
 union select 4    , 3         , NULL    
 union select 6    , 2         , 4
 union select 7    , 6         , NULL   

declare @stack table(id int, parent int, relation nvarchar, 
      stackindex int identity(1,1))

insert into @stack 
select max(id), null, 'R' from @tmp

declare @stackindex int, @id int, @relation nvarchar(50), 
      @parent int, @ChildA_id int, @ChildB_id int

while (select count(1) from @stack) > 0
begin
  select @stackindex = max(stackindex) from @stack
  select @id = id, @relation = relation, @parent = parent
  from @stack where stackindex = @stackindex

  if @id is not null
  begin

    select @childa_id = ChildA_id, @childb_id = ChildB_id
    from @tmp where id = @id 

    if @childa_id is not null
    insert into @stack(id,parent,relation)
    values(@childa_id, @id, 'A')

    if @childb_id is not null
    insert into @stack(id,parent,relation)
    values(@childb_id, @id, 'B')  

    if @relation = 'R'
    SET @xml.modify('       
insert <row><ID>{sql:variable("@id")}</ID></row>
as last
into (.)')

    if @relation = 'A'
    SET @xml.modify('       
insert <ChildA><row><ID>{sql:variable("@id")}</ID></row></ChildA>
after (//row/ID[text()=sql:variable("@parent")])[1]')

    if @relation = 'B'
    SET @xml.modify('       
insert <ChildB><row><ID>{sql:variable("@id")}</ID></row></ChildB>
as last
into (//row[ID/text()=sql:variable("@parent")])[1]')
  end

  delete from @stack where stackindex = @stackindex
end

select @xml
```